Netsh command not working, it is showing command not found
The command
netsh wlan profile name='my_wifi_name' key=clear

shows this error:
The following command was not found: wlan profile name='my_wifi_name' key=clear
The following command was not found: wlan profile='profile_name' key=clear

expecting the connected wifi password
I've tried running in admin mode, no type o error but still not working, runing on latest Windows (Windows 11).

You will need to show us the full command you're running; edit it into your question. You can copy-paste from the command prompt into a code block.

show is missing in the command.
The correct command:
netsh wlan show profile name='my_wifi_name' key=clear

It will give the expected result
